# Change xaxis range values in a plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am doing a plot of dataframe df_no_missing.

```
df_no_missing.head()
TIMESTAMP        datetime64[ns]
P_ACT_KW                float64
PERIODE_TARIF            object
P_SOUSCR                float64
SITE                     object
TARIF                    object
depassement             float64
dtype: object


Out[236]:

    TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR SITE TARIF depassement date time
        
    2015-08-01 23:10:00 248.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0.0 2015-08-01 23:10:00 
    
  
    2015-08-01 23:20:00 244.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0.0 2015-08-01 23:20:00 
    

    2015-08-01 23:30:00 243.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0.0 2015-08-01 23:30:00 
    
    
    2015-08-01 23:40:00 238.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0.0 2015-08-01 23:40:00 
 
    2015-08-01 23:50:00 234.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0.0 2015-08-01 23:50:00
```

I did a plot representing the variation of P_ACT_KW and P_SOUSCR with TIMESTAMP.
The python code is below :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 6), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearFmt)
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
x = pd.to_datetime(df_no_missing.TIMESTAMP, format="%h:%m")
y = df_no_missing.P_ACT_KW
z = df_no_missing.P_SOUSCR
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', label='P_SOUSCR')
plt.plot(x, z, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='g', label='P_ACT_KW')
plt.xlabel('temps')
plt.ylabel('puissance')
plt.title('variation de la puissance')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I get a plot like this (the attached image) [image]

My question is how can I show the timestamp in the xaxis, I mean I need the see the timestamp indicated in the dataframe  for exampel here : 23:10:00, 23:20:00 , 23:30:00, 23:40:00, 23:50:00. and not 01:00 , 04:00, 07:00 ...

Thank you if you can help me

Bests

Comment: Usually you could tell the plotting library that it should use a list of labels for the axis... see the pointplot documentation: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot . It has this `order` parameter which sets the xaxis. You could try that.

Comment: @Dr. Nefario, thank you for your reply, I add order option here in this line? plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', label='P_SOUSCR')

Comment: Yeah, try that. I hope it works.

Comment: No it does not work..

Comment: what is the output of `print(x)`?

Comment: print(x)145   2015-08-01 23:10:00
146   2015-08-01 23:20:00
147   2015-08-01 23:30:00
148   2015-08-01 23:40:00
149   2015-08-01 23:50:00
150   2015-08-02 00:00:00
163   2015-08-02 02:10:00
164   2015-08-02 02:20:00
165   2015-08-02 02:30:00
166   2015-08-02 02:40:00
167   2015-08-02 02:50:00
168   2015-08-02 03:00:00
169   2015-08-02 03:10:00
170   2015-08-02 03:20:00
171   2015-08-02 03:30:00
172   2015-08-02 03:40:00
173   2015-08-02 03:50:00
174   2015-08-02 04:00:00
              ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `set_major_locator` before `set_major_formatter`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

yearFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")

minx = pd.to_datetime( '2015-08-01 23:10:00' )
minx = pd.to_datetime( '2015-08-01 23:50:00' )

ax.set_xlim( [ minx, maxx ] )
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator( mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,10)) )  
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( yearFmt )
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, when I did ax.set_xlim( [ '23:10:00', '23:50:00' ] ) before ax.xaxis.set_major_locator( mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,10)) )  ,  it does not work

Comment: Which data type are `'23:10:00'` and `'23:50:00'` ?

Comment: TIMESTAMP        149 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: I have updated the answer, give it a try.  You can also try: `minx = x.min()` and `maxx = x.max()`, if you want the whole range in the plot.

Comment: Glad it helped, have fun!